Powers of non-subgroup element
Let $G$ be finite abelian group and $H$ its proper subgroup of non-prime order $\omega$. For $g \in G, g \notin H$ is it possible that $g^t \in H$, where $t$ is divisor of $\omega$ ?

@ancientmathematician, i have looked on a lot of groups inside certain kind of finite rings, and in that case seems it not possible. However, i was wandering is it because of ring structure or is it more general.

For any abelian group $H$ and any $t\gt 1$, there exists an abelian group $G$ that contains $H$ as a subgroup, $g\in G$, and $g\notin H$ with the property that $g^t\in H$ and $g^r\notin H$ for $r=1,\ldots,t-1$. Just take $G=H\times C_t$ and $g$ a generator of the cyclic factor of order $t$.

Sure.
Consider $\Bbb Z_4\le\Bbb Z_8.$
Then any $g\in \Bbb Z_8\setminus \Bbb Z_4$ satisfies $g^2\in \Bbb Z_4,$ because $\Bbb Z_8/\Bbb Z_4$ has order $2.$

thanks, seems i should observe structure of groups i was interesting in to prove that there are no such elements
